# Why can't we solve the consensus problem by just enforcing a new leader?

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus

I am going through this lecture series by Martin Kleppman. In this video at around 1:25, he says you can manually configure the distributed nodes to chose a leader.

If that's the case can't we just automate the process by having a different process running that just checks for the health of the leader and chooses a new leader after the leader's failure or network partition.

Why is this problem actually so hard? Why can't we solve the consensus problem by enforcing a new leader without the nodes having to actually come to an agreement What am I missing?

Comment: what if the process that chooses new leader fails? what do nodes that are not in the same partition as this process do? how does this process notify all other nodes that old leader failed and new leader was elected?

Comment: and if you have a process that never fails and can always reach everybody else, then you indeed make this process the leader and the problem is indeed solved.

Comment: * add "what happens when the monitoring process is in different partition from the leader process? to the first comment.

Comment: @Effie, I think your comments clear my doubts. Why dont u post them as an answer so I can accept?